# How to mock Void Call?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, retrofit

In my api (with Retrofit) i have lot of requests which like this:

```
public Call<Void> postAsyncReserveDevice(@NonNull ReservedWorkerData data, @NonNull String token) {

        return apiService.postReservedWorker(
                data,
                ApiPrefs.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
}
```

where i ignore result of response - he successful or not and this is important.

But I faced a problem in unit test. I need mock the api answer:

```
@Test
public void test() {
//...
when(apiService.postAsyncReserveDevice(
                eq(data), any(String.class)))
                .thenReturn(Calls.response(Any() as Void))
//...
}
```

Looks good, but when i run test case i see error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Void
```

How mock and test such methods in my api?

Comment: Have you tried using `any(Void.class)`?

Comment: nope. I make it another way. But this too works!  (my solution so stupid: `....thenReturn(Calls.response(makeVoid())); private Void makeVoid() {return null}`)

Answer (score 1):

The method returns `Call<Void>`, so why not return in the mocked method : `Mockito.any(Call.class)` ?

For example :

```
Mockito.when(mock.postAsyncReserveDevice()).thenReturn(Mockito.any(Call.class));
```

While it will produce a warning at compile time as it declares a raw `Call`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I use to use using Kotlin:

```
@Test
fun the_test() {
    val call: Call<Void> = Calls.response(makeVoid())
    `when`(apiManager.enablePushNotification(any())).thenReturn(call)
    ...
}
```

And the helper function:

```
private fun makeVoid(): Void? = null
```

That's all